# UWP C# Windows 10 IoT Alarm Clock

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, alarm, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to write an alarm clock app that can set multiple alarms to trigger output pin on Raspberry Pi. Is there any reference project out there I can refer to? or does **windows 10 alarm & clock app** reference code is available for reference?

I want to find out how to save the individual alarm and display them.
do i use a `DispatchTimer` to monitor the all the alarms set?
Thanks.

Updated:
The alarm setting intended look like this.
[image: alarm setting pivot]
[image: alarm setting dialog]

portion of my code to create the appointment is as below. But i dont seem to be able to see any appoint created as the [UWP appointment Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Appointments).

```
 private void Save_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();
        var recurrence = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentRecurrence();

        var scheduleTime = TimePicker.Time;
        var timeZoneOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
        var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, scheduleTime.Hours, scheduleTime.Minutes, 0, timeZoneOffset);
        appointment.StartTime = startTime;

        appointment.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        if(dailyAlarm.IsOn == true)
        {
            recurrence.Unit = Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentRecurrenceUnit.Daily;
        } else
        {
            if (setMonday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Monday; }
            if (setTuesday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Tuesday; }
            if (setWednesday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Wednesday; }
            if (setThursday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Thursday; }
            if (setFriday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Friday; }
            if (setSaturdayday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Saturday; }
            if (setSunday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Sunday; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us more detailed information of your alarm clock?

Comment: hi Rita, I have added the print screen of what I have been trying. when click on add new alarm, the dialog will appear to set the alarm. Once the alarm triggers, i will trigger an output pin on my rasp pi.

Comment: Have you check [Appointment calendar sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Appointments).

Comment: hi @RitaHan-MSFT is there a way to trigger an event when the appointment starts.. so I can trigger the output pin on my rasp pi in the event. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i uploaded part of my code which i define the appointment but i wasn't able to see the appointment created nor trigger. Please advise.

Comment: hi @RitaHan-MSFT I just understand from another MSFT contributor that `appointments` requires calendar app therefore it cannot be used for IoT Core.