# UWP C# Windows IoT Create Appointment

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, appointment

I have an earlier post [UWP C# Windows 10 IoT Alarm Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804888/uwp-c-sharp-windows-10-iot-alarm-clock?noredirect=1#comment82617723_47804888) which I am currently switching to use `Appointment`. 
I have a dialog to add appointment. When I run on rasp pi it doesn't seem to save the appointment & trigger it.
Please advise. 
I also hope to be able to trigger external output pin when the appointment triggers.

[image: dialog]

```
private async void Save_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();
        var recurrence = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentRecurrence();

        var scheduleTime = TimePicker.Time;
        var timeZoneOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
        var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, scheduleTime.Hours, scheduleTime.Minutes, 0, timeZoneOffset);
        appointment.StartTime = startTime;
        appointment.Subject = "Schedule Timer";

        appointment.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        if(dailyAlarm.IsOn == true)
        {
            recurrence.Unit = Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentRecurrenceUnit.Daily;
        } else
        {
            if (setMonday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Monday; }
            if (setTuesday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Tuesday; }
            if (setWednesday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Wednesday; }
            if (setThursday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Thursday; }
            if (setFriday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Friday; }
            if (setSaturdayday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Saturday; }
            if (setSunday.IsChecked == true) { recurrence.DaysOfWeek |= Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentDaysOfWeek.Sunday; }
        }



        string appointmentId = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);

        }
```

[image: Appointment Capabilities added]

Comment: You mention that when running it on the Raspberry Pi, it fails to save the appointment and trigger it.  This implies that when running on other hardware, it *does* save the appointment and trigger it.  Is that the case?

Also, do you have the "Appointments" capability specified in `Package.appxmanifest`?

Comment: hi @Naikrovek i have the "appointments" capabilities added. I set the appointment & it didn't trigger. I am not sure if I did it correctly.I am kind of lost here.

Comment: I cannot remember correctly, but I believe that Appointments saving is connected to a Microsoft Account? I will look further into this.

Comment: @mylim When you say that saving works on another computer do you mean the local computer you're debugging on? I think that possibly Iot Core may not contain the proper system of storing calendar appointments because that data is actually synced to a user's account. The namespace exists because of UWP on Windows but I cannot find documentation that suggests you cannot use this namespace with Iot Core. Perhaps post an issue on their github, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-iotcore-docs.

Comment: If the appointments aren't working why not create a simpler data structure and store that information in a file in JSON format that can easily be loaded again?

Comment: @BaileyMiller yes. I tried debug on x86 device which is my laptop before i debug on the ARM device which is my rasp pi 3. From what you have mentioned is that appointments may not work on IoT core?

Comment: By the way guys, I am pretty noob in this.. any suggestion which solution i should look into to create a 'schedule clocks schedules' and once the event triggers i can trigger a output pin from my rasp pi 3. or is there any reference project? i have been searching but can't see anything that would actually help. Thanks.

Comment: I think that perhaps you could just create your own appointment style class that loads up at app launch and handles storing the appointments and firing an event when an alarm should be going off. Essentially you are going to create a class that can store appointments, load appointments, and create a watcher thread that will be just checking if currentTime == any alarm time, if so fire an event that you can listen for.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer to your question because I cannot solve that problem, my Pi is at home and I am in the office. However, I believe that you could create something very similar to what that is doing and consume it for your application.

Here is a sample class:

```
public delegate void AlarmReadyToRing(object sender, object alarm);
public class AppointmentViewer
{
    public event AlarmReadyToRing AlarmIsReady;
    public List<object> Appointments { get; private set; }

    private Timer _AlarmClock;

    public AppointmentViewer()
    {
        LoadAppointmentsFromStorage();
        _AlarmClock = new Timer(TriggerAlarms, null, 0, (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    private void TriggerAlarms(object state)
    {

        if (DateTime.Now.Second == 59)
        {
            // Reset the timer so that it is checking every 60 seconds
            _AlarmClock.Change(0, (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds);
        }

        // Find all alarms that should be going off now
        // FindAppointments(x=>x.StartTime == Datetime.Now)
        var readyAlarms = FindAppointments(x=> 1==1);
        foreach (var alarm in readyAlarms)
        {
            AlarmIsReady?.Invoke(this, alarm);
        }
    }

    public void SaveAppointment(object appt)
    {
        // Save appointment logic
        Appointments.Add(appt);
    }

    public void LoadAppointmentsFromStorage()
    {
        // Load appointments from local storage or other
        Appointments = new List<object>();
    }

    public List<object> FindAppointments(Func<object, bool> search)
    {
        var found = Appointments.Where(search);
        return found.ToList();
    }
}


public class SomeOtherClass
{
    private static AppointmentViewer ApptViewer { get; set; } = new AppointmentViewer();

    public SomeOtherClass()
    {
        // Register for event
        ApptViewer.AlarmIsReady += DoSomething;
    }

    private void DoSomething(object sender, object alarm)
    {
        // Here is the incoming alarm that needs to be going off
        // Apply logic for app to display alarm
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. By the way, does microsoft have reference code for their windows 10 clock & alarm app? Or is there any way I can get them?

Comment: @mylim, An Appointment represents an appointment in a calendar, so 
 calendar app is necessary,but windows IoT Core does not include calendar app.Please refer to [Manage appiontments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/managing-appointments), it is for windows 10.

Comment: Hi @MichaelXu-MSFT in order for me to make an schedule alarm app for IoT core, what would be best recommended?

Comment: @mylim, I think Bailey Miller's suggestion is a simple and effective solution for your needs. I also hope there will be more discussion about that.

Comment: My example class needs fleshed out further to work correctly but if you're looking to write this alarm app I think that having total control over how the alarms are stored and what information is present will be better for you.